# Draw different colored regions in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, voronoi

I have made the following script to draw a diagram in gnuplot. There are a few number of points each enclosed within a certain area. I want to give each enclosed region a certain color. My script is as follows:

```
set terminal wxt
set yrange [0:100]
set xrange [0:100]
unset colorbox
set style arrow 1 nohead lc rgb 'black'
set style arrow 2 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set label 7 "" at 35,80 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 8 "" at 40,30 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 77.0522,58.9552 to 56.25,56.875 as 2
set label 5 "" at 10,20 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 8 "" at 40,30 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 20.3571,38.9286 to 35,-5 as 2
set label 5 "" at 10,20 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 6 "" at 25,60 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from -25.625,56.1719 to 20.3571,38.9286 as 2
set label 6 "" at 25,60 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 7 "" at 35,80 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 11.3889,79.3056 to 56.25,56.875 as 2
set label 6 "" at 25,60 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 8 "" at 40,30 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 56.25,56.875 to 20.3571,38.9286 as 2
set label 1 "" at 100,100 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 7 "" at 35,80 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 77.0522,58.9552 to 50,146.875 as 2
set label 1 "" at 100,100 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 11.3889,79.3056 to -25.625,56.1719 as 2
set label 2 "" at 0,100 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 4 "" at 0,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from -75,50 to -1000,50 as 2
set label 3 "" at 100,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 8 "" at 40,30 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 50,-25 to 87.5,50 as 2
set label 3 "" at 100,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 1 "" at 100,100 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 87.5,50 to 1100,50 as 2
set label 4 "" at 0,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 5 "" at 10,20 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from -75,50 to 35,-5 as 2
set label 4 "" at 0,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 8 "" at 40,30 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 35,-5 to 50,-25 as 2
set label 4 "" at 0,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set label 3 "" at 100,0 point pointtype 5 lc rgb 'black'
set arrow from 50,-25 to 50,-1000 as 2
plot NaN notitle
```

Which additional things will I need to add to this script to color each region?

Comment: why not use `polygon` ? type `help polygon` it's very easy

Comment: I am very new to gnuplot. can you please show me a demo code? @bibi

Comment: `set object 1 polygon from 0,0 to 1,1 to 2,0;  set object 1 fc rgb "cyan" fillstyle solid 1.0 border lt -1`

Comment: but i have two points at a time here you have three @bibi

Answer (score 2):

An old unanswered question which I  find pretty interesting. Of course, you can always manually plot your arrows and fill the areas which doesn't make sense especially for larger number of points. I am not aware that there is such a Voronoi-feature in gnuplot. This might be especially useful, when coloring a map with datapoints in an irregular grid. I am aware that gnuplot has some interpolation feature (check `help dgrid3d`).
In the past, I tried [a gnuplot implementation of Delaunay-Triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68507660/7295599), which, however, is pretty slow. Apparently, the Voronoi approach below seems to be much faster.
This procedure seems to run with `O(n^2)`, i.e. for 100, 200, 400 datapoints my old laptop needs approximately 3, 11, and 40 seconds, respectively.

What it does:

- determine for a given point `p0` the perpendicular bisectors to all other points and store them as vectors (x,y,a=angle) in `$Vectors`.
- furthermore, add the boundaries (`xmin,ymax,ymin,ymax`) as vectors as well.
- determine the vector (except the borders) with the smallest distance to point `p0` (which will be in `p1`).
- calculate all intersections of this vector with all other vectors (except itself and the previous one). Find the closest intersection in counterclockwise direction (which will be in `p2`).
- continue until you end up with the first `p1` again.

My explanations and the script are probably not so easy to understand.
Both can certainly be improved. Suggestions are welcome!
For example, maybe the use of arrays might be faster than writing to a datablock.

Comment: There seems to be still a small bug in the script. Sometimes, it can happen that some areas (especially) at the border are not filled correctly.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot 5.2.0, Sept. 2017, because of indexing of datablocks)

```
### plot Voronoi-diagram from given set of points
reset session
time0 = time(0.0)

FILE = "SO40883823.dat"

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 100
    plot '+' u (sprintf("%g %g %g",x0=rand(0), y0=rand(0), z0=(int(rand(0)*0xffffff)))) w table
    # plot FILE u 1:2:3 w table
unset table

set size square
set key noautotitle

xmin = 0  # adjust the borders
xmax = 1
ymin = 0
ymax = 1

set xrange[xmin:xmax]
set yrange[ymin:ymax]
set tics out
set offset 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01

set angle degrees
j    = {0,1}
x(i) = real(word($Data[i],1))
y(i) = real(word($Data[i],2))
z(i) = real(word($Data[i],3))

getDmin(colX,colY,colA,colL) = (L=column(colL), \
    column(colA)==column(colA) || column(0)<3 ? dmin!=dmin ? \
    (idx1=column(0),x1=column(colX),y1=column(colY),a1=column(colA),dmin=L) : L<dmin ? \
    (idx1=column(0),x1=column(colX),y1=column(colY),a1=column(colA),dmin=L) : 0 : NaN)

M(x,y,a)  = ((x-x0)*sin(a0) - (y-y0)*cos(a0))/(sin(a)*cos(a0)-sin(a0)*cos(a))
xs(x,y,a) = M(x,y,a)==0 ? NaN : x + cos(a)*M(x,y,a)
ys(x,y,a) = M(x,y,a)==0 ? NaN : y + sin(a)*M(x,y,a)

# orientation of 3 2D-points p0,p1,p2: -1=clockwise, 0=linear, +1=counterclockwise
Orientation(p0,p1,p2) = sgn((real(p1)-real(p0))*(imag(p2)-imag(p0)) - \
                            (real(p2)-real(p0))*(imag(p1)-imag(p0)))

colX = 1
colY = 2
colA = 3
colL = 4
set print $Outlines
    print ""    # initialize datablock
set print

do for [i=1:|$Data|] {
    set print $Vectors
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", x(i),  ymin,   0, y(i)-ymin, 0)  # bottom border
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", xmax,  y(i),  90, xmax-x(i), 1)  # right
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", x(i),  ymax, 180, ymax-y(i), 2)  # top
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", xmin,  y(i), 270, x(i)-xmin, 3)  # left
        x00 = x(i)
        y00 = y(i)
        z00 = z(i)
        p0 = x00 + j*y00
        do for [k=1:|$Data|] {
            x0 = (x00 + x(k))/2.
            y0 = (y00 + y(k))/2.
            dx = x(k)-x00
            dy = y(k)-y00
            a0 = dx==0 && dy==0 ? NaN : atan2(dy,dx)+90
            dL = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
            print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", x0, y0, a0, dL, k+3)
        }
    set print

    # get vector with minimal distance from p0
    dmin = NaN
    stats [*:*][*:*] $Vectors u (getDmin(colX,colY,colA,colL)) nooutput   # get x1,y1,a1,idx1
    p1 = x1 + j*y1
    set print $Outlines append
        print sprintf("# Outline for point %g: %g,%g", i, x00,y00)
    set print

    idxC = idx00 = idx1
    k = 0
    while (idxC!=idx00 || k<2) {
        k=k+1
        x0 = x1; y0=y1; a0=a1; idx0 = idx1; idx2=idx1;
        dmin = p2m = NaN
        stats [*:*][*:*] $Vectors u ($0==idx0 || $0==idxC ? NaN : \
                sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", xc=xs($1,$2,$3), \
                yc=ys($1,$2,$3), (p2=xc+j*yc, ox=Orientation(p0,p1,p2)), \
                (dL = (x0-xc)**2+(y0-yc)**2),  \
                (ox==1 ? dmin!=dmin ? \
                (x1=xc, y1=yc, a1=$3, idx1=$0, p2m=p2, dmin=dL) : dL<dmin ? \
                (x1=xc, y1=yc, a1=$3, idx1=$0, p2m=p2, dmin=dL) : dmin : dmin,$0))) nooutput
        set print $Outlines append
            print sprintf("%g %g %g % 2d",x1, y1, z00, idx0)
        set print
        p1 = p2m
        idx2 = idx1
        idxC = idx0
    }
    set print $Outlines append
        print ""; print ""
    set print
    print sprintf("Point: % 3d",i)
}

plot for [i=0:*] $Outlines u 1:2:3 index i w filledcurves lc rgb var fs solid 0.5, \
     $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 0.5 lc "black" 

print sprintf("Elapsed time: %.3f sec", time(0.0)-time0)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

OP's data from file as `SO40883823.dat` with some colors in third column. In order to create this, comment `line 10` and uncomment `line 11` in the above script. The illustration below has some additional point numbering (not in the script).

```
  0     0   0xff0000
100     0   0x00ff00
  0   100   0x0000ff
100   100   0xff00ff
 10    20   0xee82ee
 25    60   0xffff00
 35    80   0xffa544
 40    30   0x00ffff
```

[image]

With some random test data generation: 100 points

[image]

... and 400 points:

[image]