# Is there any way to color plot using 3 columns from a data file using gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a text file with three columns. I want to use the first two columns as x and y coordinates and 3rd column as the value at these coordinates. I want to color plot the values. The whole graph should be in 2d(not 3d). Please help

The data points are like

1.0 0.4 0.8
1.2 0.7 0.3
0.8 1.2 -0.5
0.4 0.4 0.0
0.3 0.6 1.2
0.9 1.0 0.5
0.2 0.4 1.0
1.5 0.9 1.4
0.3 1.3 0.3
1.3 1.0 0.4

Comment: What have you tried so far? Before you ask new questions which also don't show research effort you may want to respond to comments on your earlier questions.

Comment: What are these x,y coordinates: regular ones in a orthogonal grid or random ones? How does your data structure and format look like?

Comment: I have a data file with three columns and 10 rows. The first and second columns should be recognized as x and y coordinates, and the value from the 3rd column should be plotted at that (x, y) point as color indicating the magnitude of the value.

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any response appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plot points colored from a palette.

Check the manual and gnuplot homepage and tutorials, furthermore, check `help palette rgbformulae`.

However, from your question it's not clear whether you want the whole area filled with color (e.g. by some interpolation). Then you might want to check `help pm3d` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832907/7295599) or [triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507661/7295599) or [Voronoi graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73936869/7295599).

**Script:**

```
### plot with points and palette
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1.0   0.4   0.8
1.2   0.7   0.3
0.8   1.2  -0.5
0.4   0.4   0.0
0.3   0.6   1.2
0.9   1.0   0.5
0.2   0.4   1.0
1.5   0.9   1.4
0.3   1.3   0.3
1.3   1.0   0.4
EOD

set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05   # add some margin
set grid x,y
set palette rgb 33,13,10

plot $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 5 ps 5 lc palette z
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]